# ¿ Cómo compartir archivos en whatsApp desde un botón flotante en html y jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, whatsapp

Buenas tardes con cada uno de ustedes, bueno tengo una gran consulta, actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación para compartir archivos, en la cual existe un botón flotante de WhatsApp para enviar el documento PDF, pero no se como adjuntar el archivo ya que solo me permite enviar mensajes de texto.
Ejemplo del botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de clicar en el icono de WhatsApp el aplicativo genera un pdf para compartir con el cliente, pero hasta el momento no logro encontrar la solución.

¿Por favor alguien me puede ayudar.?

Estoy realizando en jquery:

```
function openApiWhatsApp(rutapdf) {
   // rutapdf => es la ruta del archivo pdf que esta en el servidor
   var opens = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+51999999999&text="+rutapdf;
   window.open(opens);
}
```

Lo que me gustaría es adjuntar el archivo directamente y abrir la aplicación de WhatsApp en la pc en caso de estar instalado, caso contrario abrir WhatsApp Web con el archivo adjunto.

Comment: Hola pudiste realizarlo? si es así por favor compartir solución.

Answer (score 4):

Actualmente solo se puede enviar texto con esta API (que puede incluir links pero no adjuntos).

Existen APIs adicionales que pueden hacerlo (WhatsApp Business API)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/media

y otras alternativas que pueden manejarlo de manera mas conveniente: https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api

En cualquiera de estos casos necesitas una cuenta Facebook Business, configuracion adicional, un servidor que procesa los mensajes en un backend, y obviamente un acceso a la API mediante la API de login

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages#prereq

Comment: Me parece una buena respuesta, ya que es general y aclara la duda del usuario, si hay algún voto negativo por esta respuesta seria de muy mal gusto, pues esta me parece totalmente valida dado sus argumentos y documentación. pienso que en stackoverflow algunas cosas no necesariamente deberian llevar codigo para poder ser buenas respuestas.